# FBLoginView button with sharp corners

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using FBLoginView in an IOS app.

Can I change the button of FBLoginView to have sharp instead of round corners?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try following code (**swift 3**) to make the corners look sharp ([see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVDgG.png)).

```
loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.36, blue:0.68, alpha:1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use a custom button for that, you get `FBLoginView` from a third party library, and would have to work within the constraints set by the third party library.

Nevertheless, in case `FBLoginView` uses a layer's `cornerRadius` to round itself internally, you could inspect the view hierarchy and set the corner radius of the offending view to `0.0` to get sharp edges.

Comment: I tried to get into the subview - the <button>.layer.cornerRadius is already 0... (so I asked here...)

Comment: @Boaz In that case, you'd have to use a custom button.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the corners in FBLoginView are from the background image of the button, so although this is a hack - changing it solves the problem:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.frame = CGRectMake(21, 108, 279, 37);
for (UIView *subview in loginView.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *FBButton = (UIButton *)subview;
        [FBButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_rect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
loginView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```